# How to display selected value in pre-defined dropdownlist list in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have HTML dropdown list with pre-defined values. I want display one of the specific values from my controller. In a desktop application I would simply write `dropdownName.SelectedItem = "";`, how can I do this in asp.Net?

If I want to select a specific value (B for example), what will my code be like?
e.g. `Request["pName"] = "B";`.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<select id="pName" name="pName" class="input-large form-control" style="width:auto">
    <option selected disabled>Select Option</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: *I want display one of the specific values from my controller*.. yet your HTML is hard-coded for a dropdownlist.. Can you show your controller code?

Comment: look at this example https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I didn't see that. Nice catch. OP please update the question with your controller code.

Comment: That is my question what I have to write in my controller. I am not getting the idea about it. @BviLLe_Kid . My controller actionresult is empty now.

Comment: so will your dropdownlist be populated from what is in a database table.. or are you going to just hard-code values in?

Comment: Yes, my specification is to use hard-coded values because I am parsing data from XML file. I want to display the similar value from my pre-defined hard-coded values. Suppose, if I get B from my XML file then it will show B. @BviLLe_Kid .

Comment: I think @RazvanDumitru answer does what you're looking for.

Comment: So, you will need to parse the XML and to compute a list of options that will be your list of SelectListItem. And if you'll get B as the selected option, you will need to set the Selected = true for that SelectListItem.

Comment: Also, as i said, is better to create a class that will deal with all this mapping from XML to List<SelectListItem> and keep your controller as clean as you can.

Comment: Exactly @RazvanDumitru . Can you please explain it more with a code example please?

Comment: I need to know how your XML structure is looking and parsing xml's isn't really the scope of this question.

Comment: Here is a sample of my XML version. I do not need parsing procedure. I have done it already.

        <machine_data>
    <name>Machine Name</name>
    <parser>A</parser>
    <versionNumber>2010</versionNumber>
  </machine_data>

Comment: So, if you parsed your xml, then you have a list of dto's. Use those dto's to create a list of options which will be your `List<SelectListItem>` . A dto is something like the following: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5 . A transfer object. You will need a mapping from that list of transfer objects to a list of wanted options. DTO -> SelectListItem

Answer (score 0):

Technically you need a select list and a html dropdownlist helper:

```
 public ActionResult SelectCategory() {

         var viewModel = new ViewModel();

         List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

         items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "A"});

         items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "B" });

         // SelectListItem has a boolean property Selected, which is false by default 
         items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "C", Value = "C", Selected = true });

         viewModel.CategoryType = items;

         return View();

     }
```

And in your view:

```
  @model ViewModel
  @Html.DropDownList("CategoryType")
```

Please be aware that technically these options for computing the `List<SelectListItem>` probably are from database and it's better to create a static class for computing this list and other similar lists (which are based on nomenclatures)

Controller code must be clean.

Comment: So where you have `ViewBag.parserName = "B"`, you need to create a `ViewModel` class and to compute a `List` of `SelectListItem`. After that you need to create a property in your `ViewModel` class `public List<SelectListItem> CategoryType`, which will be set to be that list of items. And in your view, exactly what i've described earlier.